# how to set LinearLayout in bottom of FrameLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have this code :

```
         FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);
         LinearLayout gameWidgets = new LinearLayout (this);
         game.addView(gameWidgets);
```

How to set the LinearLayout in the buttom of the FrameLayout ?

Comment: What? `LinearLayout in the FrameLayout of the LinearLayout` :O I am bit confused, may be it the Tea that I am taking right now :-|

Comment: @M-WaJeEh (+1)provide me 1 cup tea too.

Comment: sorry I edit that @M-WaJeEh

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this,

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

game.addView(GameWidgets, params);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM
                    | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
game.addView(GameWidgets, p);
```